# Обработка касаний в фрагментах в Андроид приложении

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! У меня класс наследуется от Fragment. Можно ли как-нибудь обработать касание по экрану? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А у меня есть веб камера. Можно я поеду домой? У фрагмента есть свой View, а у View можно установить OnTouchListener. Вперед, устанавливайте.